# API Handling with conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run an API call based off 2 conditions and I'm not sure the best way of going about this.

I've tried doing the following with and `if..else` statement:

```
let data;

if (condition == true) {
  if (condition == true) {
    LocalCall1() // mutate data variable
  } else {
   ApiCall1() // mutate data variable
    }
  } else {
   ApiCall1() // mutate data variable
 }
```

However, `ApiCall1()` is 40 lines long so I can't just copy and paste it into both else blocks. Also, this `if...else` statement is within a function so I was told I cannot just create another function within this one because it'll make it hard to test.

What is the best way of going about this?

EDIT - More code for reference:

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. check if the client has the data in local storage
2. if not, get it from server
3. if so, check the version is correct
4. if version is incorrect, get data from server

```
  let data;

  if (localStorage.getItem('constants')) {
    const localStorageConstants = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('constants'));
    if (+localStorageConstants.version === serverVersion) {
      data = localStorageConstants.data;
    } else {
      const { data: response } = await apollo.query({ query });
      if (!response) {
        return {};
      }
      data = response;
      localStorage.setItem('constants', JSON.stringify({ version: serverVersion, data }));
    }
  } else {
    const { data: response } = await apollo.query({ query });
    if (!response) {
      return {};
    }
    data = response;
    localStorage.setItem('constants', JSON.stringify({ version: serverVersion, data }));
  }
```

I cannot put both conditions in one if statement because I have to use JSON.parse on the `constants` data from local storage. I was told that I cannot use JSON.parse before the if...else statement because then I would be creating a variable that might not be used and that'd be unnecessary memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just merge the 2 if/else-statements like this?

```
if (condition1 === true && condition2 === true) {
    LocalCall1()
} else {
    ApiCall1()
}
```

Edit:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('constants') && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('constants')).version === serverVersion) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('constants')).data; 
} else {
    const { response } = await apollo.query({ query });
    if (!response) return {};
    localStorage.setItem('constants', JSON.stringify({ version: serverVersion, data: response }));
  }
```

Comment: I can't because I have to use `JSON.parse` on a variable before the 2nd if statement. I was planning on just using `JSON.parse` outside of the `if...else` statement, but I was told I cannot declare a variable if we might not use it as it will cause unnecessary memory load

Comment: Added a little more!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
(firstCondition && secondCondition)? LocalCall1(); : ApiCall1();
```

Comment: I added a little more code for context. I can't put the first and second in one call since the 2nd condition is based off the first.

Comment: @Jav, it is as simple as you wrote in your question point 1,2,3 and 4. Just convert those line to if else condition

Answer (score 0):

Binary...

```
if(condition1 && condition2) res = 3;
if(!condition1 && condition2) res = 2;
if(condition1 && !condition2) res = 1;
if(!condition1 && !condition2) res = 0;
```

...and then so whatever you want to do based on res.

Comment: condition 2 is based off a `JSON.parse` that I do after the `condition1` if statement, so I can't put both conditions on one line

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late for you but it may help someone else in future.

Create a boolean flag and set it True every time ApiCall1() needs to be executed. Outside the outer if condition invoke ApiCall1() if this flag is true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).